# Using existing table for AUTH_USER_MODEL is it possible for a Django model field name to refer to database field name that is different

Tags: django, django-models

As the title suggests, I am playing with using an existing table for the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` using `AbstractUser`. Have to `--fake` the migration. Any additional columns I have to add to the DB manually and then to the model as some errors come up. Not ideal.

Anyway, when I got to `./manage.py createsuperuser` I get errors related to fields not existing that it requires: `is_superuser`, `is_staff`, etc. The thing is there are fields in the table for this already, just have a slightly different name. I could just change the name.

But it got me wondering if there is something built in to Django to cast an ORM field name to a table field name. Something like:

```
class Meta:
    db_table = 'Users'
```

Where Django assumes the name, unless it is otherwise specified.

My quick glimpse through the documentation didn't immediately yield anything.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.

# Extend the User model
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    cono = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    ip_whitelist_1 = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    ip_whitelist_2 = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    ip_whitelist_3 = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    password_changed = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    security_q1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    security_q2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    security_a1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    security_a2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    login_unlock_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    challenge_unlock_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    # having to add these
    is_superuser = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    is_anonymous = False
    is_authenticated = True

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Users'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use the [db-column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#db-column) option:

```
    # having to add these
    is_superuser = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column="YOU_NAME1", blank=True, null=True)
    #                                         ^^^^^^
    is_staff = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column="YOU_NAME2", blank=True, null=True)
    #                                         ^^^^^^
    is_active = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column="YOU_NAME3", blank=True, null=True)
    #                                         ^^^^^^
```